# I want to change zeros to blanks in sheets using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, spreadsheet

I'm new to using apps script and I'm just trying this out. I want to convert zeros to blanks.

This is the code I've managed to create, but it doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it.

```
    function zero() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
      var selectedRange = ss.getActiveRange()
      var selectedValues = selectedRange.getValues()
      var selectedColumns = selectedRange.getWidth()
      var selectedRows = selectedRange.getHeight()
    
        for(i = 0; i<selectedRows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j<selectedColumns; j++) {
          if (selectedValues[i][j] = 0) {
            selectedRange.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setValue(" ")
          }
        }
      }
    }

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Blank')
      .addItem('Change zero to blank', 'zero')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script, I think that your if statement of `if (selectedValues[i][j] = 0) {}` is required to be modified. If the cell value is the number of `0`, please use `===` instead of `==`. So, when your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function zero() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var selectedRange = ss.getActiveRange();
  var selectedValues = selectedRange.getValues();
  var selectedColumns = selectedRange.getWidth();
  var selectedRows = selectedRange.getHeight();
  for (i = 0; i < selectedRows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < selectedColumns; j++) {
      if (selectedValues[i][j] === 0) {
        selectedRange.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setValue(" ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- If you want to change the number of `0` to blank, you can also use `selectedRange.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setValue(null);` instead of `selectedRange.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setValue(" ");`.
- I think that when `setValue` is used in a loop, the process cost will be high. In your situation, the following script can be used.

  ```
    function zero() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var selectedRange = ss.getActiveRange();
      selectedRange.createTextFinder("0").matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith(" "); // or .replaceAllWith("");
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: I found this very helpful. Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "process cost will be high".

Comment: @Olatoye Oluwaseun Thank you for replying. About the process cost, in this case, it means the processing time. When `setValue` is used in a loop, the processing time will belong. You can see my report at https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4 . If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.